# Linking my filter from my product page to the drop-down on my homepage

Tags: javascript, filter, drop-down-menu, internal-link

So I created a filter product page using objects and array in JavaScript but I want to be able to link each filter to my header drop-down on my homepage and contact me page, please how do I do that?

I tried using internal hyperlinks to connect the button of each filter to the drop-down but it didn't work

Comment: Can you share the example code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.